# how to send a check box value as a php parameter on a button click

Tags: php, parameters, popupwindow

hi i have a check box and a button which opens a popup window on a button click i am sending a parameter which works fine now i have added a check box and i want to send its value as a parameter too and i am stuck here n have no idea of what has to be done
here is my script

```
  <?php 
        if($addflag == 0){
           echo "<td>";
               echo '<font color="red"><strong>Print On Letter Head</strong></font><input type="checkbox" id="dtype" name="dtype" value="1" checked></input>';
               echo '<input class="cmdprint" type="button" id="submit" name="print" value="Print" onclick="window.open(\'quotprin.php?vouchno='.$getvouch.'&dtype=\'document.getElementById(\'status1\').value;\'\',\'popUpWindow\',\'height=800,width=950,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes\');"></td>';
           echo "<td>";
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somthing like this should work.

on suggestion try to avoid inline js and use functions instead.
other suggestion try to use `checked="checked"` instead of `checked`.

add this to javascript

```
<?php
if($addflag == 0){
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
function mopen(){
var mobj=document.getElementById(\'dtype\');
var mval=mobj.value;
window.open(\'quotprin.php?vouchno='.$getvouch.'&dtype=mval\',\'popUpWindow\',\'height=800,width=950,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes\');
</script>
';
}
```

and the PHP

```
<?php
if($addflag == 0){
echo "<td>";
echo '<font color="red"><strong>Print On Letter Head</strong></font>
<input type="checkbox" id="dtype" name="dtype" value="1" checked="checked" />';
echo '<input class="cmdprint" type="button" id="submit" name="print" value="Print" onclick="mopen();"></td>';
echo "<td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: thnks alot that really helped